# system(): Spaces in strings

Tags: c++

I'm using the `system()` function in my program to call a node application that adds passed in data to my database.

```
string data1 = "This is data";
string data2 = "data";
system(("node connect.js "+data1+" "+data2).c_str());
cout << data1 << endl << data2;
```

Output for cout:

> This is data
>
> data

But when I print out the passed through arguments in node, this is what happens

> this
>
> is

As I understand it, the `system()` function is treating the string `data1`  as 3 separate arguments instead of just one.  Is there a way to make the `system()` function ignore those spaces, or do I need to remove the spaces from the string?  I'd prefer to keep the spaces if at all possible for readability.

Edit: fixed the system function

Comment: That has nothing to do with `system` it's how the shell interprets the arguments

Comment: Please edit your question to contain [mcve], code as shown would not even compile

Comment: @UnholySheep is there anyway to get around that issue?  I know how to do it with directories but would is be possible using arguments?